# Pandas DataFrame - adding columns in for loop vs another approach

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

we have measurements for n points (say 22 points) over a period of time stored in a real time store. now we are looking for some understanding of trends for points mentioned above. In order to gain an objective we read measurements into a pandas DataFrame (python). Within this DataFrame points are now columns and rows are respective measurement time.

We would like to extend data frame with new columns for mean and std by inserting 'mean' and 'std' columns for each existing column, being a particular measurement. This means two new columns per 22 measurement points.

Now question is whether above is best achieved adding new mean and std columns while iterating existing columns or is there another more effective DataFrame built in operation or tricks?

Our understanding is that updating of DataFrame in a for loop would by far be worst practice.

Thanks for any comment or proposal.

Comment: If there are 22 points per period, and 1000 samples, are you saying you want 22 means or 1000 means?

Comment: If you need means and std of the 22 points/columns, why do you want the columns? Aren't the values of the mean or standard deviation going to be the same throughout the column. In that case you can create a new dataframe that stores this information. Coming to your question, try looking into the `.apply()` method of dataframe.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - 22 means and 22 std but over all rows. So it would be 1000 means per point which is why we think to add new column with all means for point

Comment: @ClockSlave - where does that happen? I mean do I iterate columns and then do I issue apply per column? I might always create transpose and iterate rows if that makes things easier.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, I guess this is what you are looking for -

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = (1000,22))) # created an example dataframe
df.loc[:, 'means'] = df.mean(axis = 1)
df.loc[:, 'std'] = df.mean(axis = 1)
```